# How to delete a reverted commit that is not removed?

Tags: git

I created a branch from the master and made some modifications.

I gave the `push`, and when I was going to open the PR, I noticed that a file was not supposed to go on this branch, with this I made the mistake of reverting the commits, however now I am not able to delete these commits.

**The commits are only locally**, the PR has not been opened and much less dipped.

How do I undo the bullshit I did? I want to delete all the commits marked in red in the image below, I've tried to drop, I've tried to reset the commit hard, but they don't disappear.

[image]

Comment: `git reset` doesn't delete commits. Are those commits an ancestor of a commit that has a branch name or tag associated with it?

Comment: @evolutionxbox 
I don't know exactly what I meant by "ancestor". But these commits were made on a new branch from the master, and the commits with "Revert" written, git itself did when reverting such a commit.

Comment: `git rebase` is the way to do this. Git rebase starting at the furthest back "good" commit, and then erase all of the lines containing the commits you do not want (don't just use my comment on it, check other posts). *Technically*, even if you make a mistake with this, the SHA's should be recoverable, but that could be difficult for you to figure out. Instead, I would suggest creating a new branch, fixing the history, and when you are POSITIVE it is how you want it, forcibly push to your local main branch from that. This has to be forced because the histories will be different.

Comment: @Kraigolas: `git rebase -i`, specifically.